# Conservation of momentum of electron-photon pair in Bohr's Model

Tags: photons, atomic-physics

I was reading the book: 'Fundamentals of Physics by Halliday, Resnick and Walker', and in its 'Photons and matter waves' Chapter they discuss about the interactions of photons with electrons.

Specifically in the discussion of Compton Effect, they *explicitly* used the law of conservation of momentum for the electron-photon pair.

Now, we also know that in the Bohr's Model of single-electron atom, the velocity of an electron in $n^th$ orbit of an atom with atomic number $Z$ is given by:
$$v=v_0\left(\frac{Z}{n}\right)$$
where $v_0$ is a constant with the appropriate dimensions.

By this formula we see that when (for example), an electron goes from $n=1$ to $n=2$, after absorbing a photon, speed has been halved.

But here the law of conservation of momentum of the electron-photon pair doesn't seem to be applicable, because the final momentum(of the electron) is smaller in magnitude as compared to the intial value(of electron-photon pair).

Also, there doesn't seem to be any dependence on the angle between the velocity vectors, as was the case in Compton Effect.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Wouldn't the momentum be transferred to the whole atom?

Comment: @IshanDeo If you are asking me(as is obvious from your statement), then please don't beacuse I myself have the doubt. But if you are telling me the answer, then please post it in a complete answer. Or at least, **please** write your comment as a statement, not as a question.